# How to restrict an S3 bucket to a specific IAM user to only access it via API token

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We have an app similar to Dropbox where we store user's files in S3. The only way for the user to do so is via the app (similar to dropbox).

Due to valid privacy concerns, we want to restrict the access of that S3 bucket so the contents of the bucket can only be access from via the app - for which we've created the API token and use that to access the contents.

We don't even want the root account to be able to traverse the contents of that specific S3 bucket.

However, in the event that some administrative intervention is needed, we want to be able to grant a specific user account the ability to physically traverse into the S3 bucket and do whatever is required at that point of time. Once said administrative task is completed, the access should be revoked.

Have you folks encountered this kind of scenario? How would one go about implementing something like this?

Thanks for your thoughts

Comment: I believe you can achieve this with S3 bucket policies, however, you're not going to be able to prevent the root account from accessing S3. What would the point of the root account be if that were the case?

Answer (score 0):

The **root credentials** associated with an AWS account has full permissions. And even if they don't, they have the ability to remove blocking permissions. Companies typically secure their root login by adding a multi-factor authentication (MFA) device and locking it in a safe.

You can easily write a **Bucket Policy** that denies all access except to a specific IAM User, and your application can either use that IAM User to either:

- Download content and then **serve it directly** to clients, or
- Create **pre-signed URLs** that grant time-limited access to private objects in Amazon S3, then provide those URLs to clients so that they can download the object from Amazon S3

**Temporary access** can be granted by modifying the Bucket Policy. You should, of course, restrict the ability for your normal users to modify Bucket Policies.

For this extra-sensitive information, you should probably **create a separate AWS Account**. That way, only a select few people would have any access to that account, which prevents accidentally granting access. For example, if a Systems Administrator is granted access to all S3 buckets in Account A, they would have no access to buckets in Account B.